# How to obtain ITypeDescriptorContext and IServiceProvider in inherited ControlDesigner class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

I have inherited `ControlDesigner` class into `MyControlDesigner`.

In this class I need to obtain objects behind `ITypeDescriptorContext` and `IServiceProvider` interfaces, but I don't know how :(

I need these 2 interfaces to pass them in method, but I can't find them inside any other object.

Can somebody please help me.

Thank you

Best regards 
Bojan

Comment: It's an old question and probably you don't need the answer anymore, but future readers may find [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811446/how-to-obtain-itypedescriptorcontext-and-iserviceprovider-in-inherited-controlde#43827054) below useful.

Answer (score 5):

There is an internal class `EditorServiceContext` in `System.Design` assembly which has implemented `ITypeDescriptorContext`, `IServiceProvider` and `IWindowsFormsEditorService`.

You can find it and create an instance of the class or use its static methods to satisfy your requirement. For example to show the editor for a property, you can use it this way:

```
var editorServiceContext = typeof(ControlDesigner).Assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(x => x.Name == "EditorServiceContext").FirstOrDefault();
var editValue = editorServiceContext.GetMethod("EditValue",
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static |
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);
editValue.Invoke(null, new object[] { this, this.Component, "The Property Name" });
```

---

If for any reason you need the source of the class to apply some changes to it, here is the code for that class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Drawing.Design;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

internal class EditorServiceContext : 
    IWindowsFormsEditorService, ITypeDescriptorContext, IServiceProvider
{
    // Fields
    private IComponentChangeService _componentChangeSvc;
    private ComponentDesigner _designer;
    private PropertyDescriptor _targetProperty;

    // Methods
    internal EditorServiceContext(ComponentDesigner designer)
    {
        this._designer = designer;
    }

    internal EditorServiceContext(ComponentDesigner designer, PropertyDescriptor prop)
    {
        this._designer = designer;
        this._targetProperty = prop;
        if (prop == null)
        {
            prop = TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultProperty(designer.Component);
            if ((prop != null) && typeof(ICollection).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType))
            {
                this._targetProperty = prop;
            }
        }
    }

    internal EditorServiceContext(ComponentDesigner designer, PropertyDescriptor prop, string newVerbText) : this(designer, prop)
    {
        this._designer.Verbs.Add(new DesignerVerb(newVerbText, new EventHandler(this.OnEditItems)));
    }

    public static object EditValue(ComponentDesigner designer, object objectToChange, string propName)
    {
        PropertyDescriptor prop = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(objectToChange)[propName];
        EditorServiceContext context = new EditorServiceContext(designer, prop);
        object obj2 = prop.GetValue(objectToChange);
        object obj3 = (prop.GetEditor(typeof(UITypeEditor)) as UITypeEditor).EditValue(context, context, obj2);
        if (obj3 != obj2)
        {
            try
            {
                prop.SetValue(objectToChange, obj3);
            }
            catch (CheckoutException)
            {
            }
        }
        return obj3;
    }

    private void OnEditItems(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object component = this._targetProperty.GetValue(this._designer.Component);
        if (component != null)
        {
            CollectionEditor editor = TypeDescriptor.GetEditor(component, typeof(UITypeEditor)) as CollectionEditor;
            if (editor != null)
            {
                editor.EditValue(this, this, component);
            }
        }
    }

    void ITypeDescriptorContext.OnComponentChanged()
    {
        this.ChangeService.OnComponentChanged(this._designer.Component, this._targetProperty, null, null);
    }

    bool ITypeDescriptorContext.OnComponentChanging()
    {
        try
        {
            this.ChangeService.OnComponentChanging(this._designer.Component, this._targetProperty);
        }
        catch (CheckoutException exception1)
        {
            if (exception1 != CheckoutException.Canceled)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    object IServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if ((serviceType == typeof(ITypeDescriptorContext)) || (serviceType == typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService)))
        {
            return this;
        }
        if ((this._designer.Component != null) && (this._designer.Component.Site != null))
        {
            return this._designer.Component.Site.GetService(serviceType);
        }
        return null;
    }

    void IWindowsFormsEditorService.CloseDropDown()
    {
    }

    void IWindowsFormsEditorService.DropDownControl(Control control)
    {
    }

    DialogResult IWindowsFormsEditorService.ShowDialog(Form dialog)
    {
        IUIService service = (IUIService)((IServiceProvider)this).GetService(typeof(IUIService));
        if (service != null)
        {
            return service.ShowDialog(dialog);
        }
        return dialog.ShowDialog(this._designer.Component as IWin32Window);
    }

    // Properties
    private IComponentChangeService ChangeService
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._componentChangeSvc == null)
            {
                this._componentChangeSvc = (IComponentChangeService)((IServiceProvider)this).GetService(typeof(IComponentChangeService));
            }
            return this._componentChangeSvc;
        }
    }

    IContainer ITypeDescriptorContext.Container
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._designer.Component.Site != null)
            {
                return this._designer.Component.Site.Container;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    object ITypeDescriptorContext.Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return this._designer.Component;
        }
    }

    PropertyDescriptor ITypeDescriptorContext.PropertyDescriptor
    {
        get
        {
            return this._targetProperty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tested the class for [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43826903/3110834). Also a I've implemented a lighter version for [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36794920/3110834) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36314635/3110834).

Answer (score 1):

Component.Site implements IServiceProvider, IDK about ITypeDescriptorContext, i'm looking for it too...

To get IServiceProvider you can do: var sp = (IServiceProvider)Component.Site;

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it work. I will continue to searching for ITypeDescriptorContext. If I find it, I will write it here. Thanks again.

Comment: It's an old question and probably you don't need the answer anymore, but future readers may find [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811446/how-to-obtain-itypedescriptorcontext-and-iserviceprovider-in-inherited-controlde#43827054) below useful.