# How to use built-in editors for a exposed properties in User Controls - Mask Property Editor Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, windows-forms-designer, maskedtextbox

I think there is a simple solution for my stupid question but I just can't solve it today.

I have a User Control that has a `MaskedTextBox` Control in itself. I have also exposed a few of its properties for the user to modify.

One of these properties is `Mask` property which I want to expose with the ability of starting an editor with predefined values like in a normal MaskedTextBox control.

So I created a public property InputMask and set up everything so that it can work but after showing the editor, I get an error dialog which contains this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

If i don't use editor and copy a mask or set it trough code works without problems.

Here is a code sample:

```
...
MaskedTextBox maskedtextbox;
myUserControl()
{
    ...
    maskedtextbox = new MaskedTextBox(){
        some stuff...
    };
}

[DefaultValue("")]
[Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.MaskPropertyEditor, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
[Localizable(true)]
[MergableProperty(false)]
[RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)]
public string InputMask
{
    get { return this.maskedtextbox.Mask; }
    set { this.maskedtextbox.Mask = value; }
}
```

Comment: It's not that simple in this case. In normal cases it's enough to register ui type editor and you don't need to do anything extra. But in `MaskPropertyEditor` case, when editing the property, the editor expect the the property belong to a `MaskedTextBox`. So you should exactly edit the `Mask` property of the `MaskedTextBox` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In normal cases it's enough to register UI type editor and you don't need to do anything extra. But in `MaskPropertyEditor` case, when editing the property, the editor expect the the property belong to a `MaskedTextBox` and converts [`ITypeDescriptorContext.Instance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.itypedescriptorcontext.instance?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#System_ComponentModel_ITypeDescriptorContext_Instance) to `MaskedTextBox` and since our editing `Mask` property belongs to our `UserControl` which is not a masked text box, a null reference exception will throw.

To solve the problem, you need to create a custom `UITypeEditor` and override `EditValue` and edit `Mask` property of the private `MaskedTextBox` field. To do so, we need to create an instance of `ITypeDescriptorContext` containing the `MaskedTextBox` and pass it to `EditValue` method of the editor.

Here is the implementations.

**UserControl**

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    MaskedTextBox maskedTextBox;
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        maskedTextBox = new MaskedTextBox();
    }

    [Editor(typeof(MaskEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public string Mask
    {
        get { return maskedTextBox.Mask; }
        set { maskedTextBox.Mask = value; }
    }
}
```

**Editor**

```
public class MaskEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
    }
    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, 
                                     IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        var field = context.Instance.GetType().GetField("maskedTextBox",
                       System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                       System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        var maskedTextBox = (MaskedTextBox)field.GetValue(context.Instance);
        var maskProperty = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(maskedTextBox)["Mask"];
        var tdc = new TypeDescriptionContext(maskedTextBox, maskProperty);
        var editor = (UITypeEditor)maskProperty.GetEditor(typeof(UITypeEditor));
        return editor.EditValue(tdc, provider, value);
    }
}
```

**ITypeDescriptionContext Implementation**

```
public class TypeDescriptionContext : ITypeDescriptorContext
{
    private Control editingObject;
    private PropertyDescriptor editingProperty;
    public TypeDescriptionContext(Control obj, PropertyDescriptor property)
    {
        editingObject = obj;
        editingProperty = property;
    }
    public IContainer Container
    {
        get { return editingObject.Container; }
    }
    public object Instance
    {
        get { return editingObject; }
    }
    public void OnComponentChanged()
    {
    }
    public bool OnComponentChanging()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public PropertyDescriptor PropertyDescriptor
    {
        get { return editingProperty; }
    }
    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return editingObject.Site.GetService(serviceType);
    }
}
```

The project may need to be reloaded before Visual Studio can recognize the new `UITypeEditor`

Comment: Thank you very much. It works great. I'am more of a Photoshop person (Designer over 10 year) than a C# developer but thanks to you helping me a couple of times I designed and implemented a nice UI for a windows forms application. Thank you.